# import GsonFactory in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gson

I have been looking all over to why i cannot use Gson in particular gsonFactory from any library i use.

I am using eclipse, my project has maven and I am running OS X

I am looking at this guide [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) and whenever i try and create `jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();` the GsonFactory cannot be resolved.

Now I have added several libraries as maven dependencies to no avail,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and also downloaded several jars but none of them resolve `GsonFactory`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That class is part of the GSON extensions to Google HTTP client library. So you just need to add [a dependency for it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-gson). The current latest version is 1.21.0, so you could have:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```